# trying to get my views.py and urls.py to work properly

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, server

I am currently trying to get my database that I created to display on my Djnago server however I keep getting errors for my FruitModel saying that there are no objects however I have created objects for the FruitModel in my datbase using "record = FruitModel.objects.create(name='banana', price='4.00').
I am also getting an unable to display error for my urls when I loaded up my server.
Here is my code for
Views.py and for urls.py:

```
(views.py code)
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from catalog.models import FruitModel
from catalog.forms import FruitForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def FruitView(request):
    fruit = FruitModel.objects.all()
 
    html = ''
    for fruits in fruit:
        var = f'<li> {fruits.name} </li><br>'
        html = html + var
    return HttpResponse(html,status = 200)

def FruitIDView(request,name):
    fruits = FruitModel.objects.get(name = f'{fruits.name}')

    html = f'<h2>{fruits.name}</h2><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html, status=200)

(urls.py code)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from catalog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^FruitView/?$', views.FruitView),
]
```

Comment: can you plaese show us the tracebacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this changes:

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^FruitView/?$', views.FruitView),
    path('FruitIDView/<str:naam>', views.FruitIDView), #use path instead of url
]

#models.py (if not created)

class FruitModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()


#views.py
def FruitView(request):
    fruit = FruitModel.objects.all()
 
    html = ''
    for fruits in fruit:
        var = f'<li> {fruits.name} </li><br>'
        html = html + var
    return HttpResponse(html,status = 200)

def FruitIDView(request,naam):
    fruits = FruitModel.objects.get(name = naam) #how can  you use fruits.name here

    html = f'<h2>{fruits.name}</h2><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html, status=200)

#admin.py (if not created)

from .models import *
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(FruitModel)
```